# jQuery call a function based on a value?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, append

So let's assume that I have a div with some value in it:

```
<div id="Good">
   <div id="Test4">
      <div class="hidden">
         <div class="weight">147</div>
```

Then let's say I wanted to use jQuery to append the whole test4 div to another div (with the same structure) called "bad" if the value was less than 100?

Right now I have my append in order but I control it with onClick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#Test4').click(function() {
    $('#Test4').appendTo('#bad')
 });
});
</script>
```

If this isn't possible could someone recommend a way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: what's wrong with your code? isn't that what u r trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to parse that value as an integer, and then test it:

```
$("#test4").on("click", function(){
    if ( +$(".weight", this).text() < 100 )
        $(this).appendTo("#bad");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/fTeMH/

Comment: Would there be some way to make this happen without a click?

Comment: @HunderingThooves Like when the page loads?

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking of updating the values either via refresh or via ajax, so having this be a persistent script seems like it would better serve the problem.   Is that possible with jQuery?  I know it's event based...

Comment: @HunderingThooves You could create a function that re-checks all of the values, and call that anytime you update the values.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?  I'm (very) new to jQuery and I've been a bit lost with the syntax (coming from java).  Could you point me somewhere that might help?

Comment: @HunderingThooves How are you loading in new values? Are you using jQuery.Ajax? If so, from the `success:` callback, you can issue a call to a function that will re-check all of the values.

Comment: In honesty, I haven't gotten to that point yet.  The webpage is likely going to be displayed using jsp, so it'll either be pulling the values from the java program or itself and updating via ajax or a timed page refresh, I'm undecided on which though.

Comment: @HunderingThooves Feel free to return when you approach that bridge ;)

Comment: I'm going to comment back here then :)  Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: Just as a quick follow-up, I tried implementing this in real data that I'm using and I'm able to get it to work on jsfiddle, but not on my real data... I have NO idea why though.

Comment: @HunderingThooves I'll need to see the structure of the real data to assist you further.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3BR4s/ is a direct copy-paste from my program, but it will NOT move "Ercot" when I click on it in google Chrome....Despite it working FINE in jsfiddle....

Comment: @HunderingThooves Try placing the code *inside* the document ready block where the rest of your code is.

Comment: Seriously though, you rock, thank you so much for the help.   I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
foo = document.getElementById("Test4")
bar = document.getElementById("bad")

bar.appendChild(foo)
```